# What is the equivalent for `az account set` in the Azure Python SDK?

Tags: python, azure-cli, azure-sdk

What is the equivalent to [`az account set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/account?view=azure-cli-latest#az_account_set) Azure using Python SDK?

I'd like to select a `subscription` to act upon using Python script.

**Example:**

In a `bash` script, I'd choose the subscription to act on using `az account set --subscription $desiredSub`. I want to know the equivalent in Azure Pythons SDK.

Comment: Please expand your answer to clarify what you are asking. Do you mean you want to modify the CLI configuration via Python or you are writing a program and you want to authenticate with Azure? For the first case, look into modules such as azure-cli-core https://pypi.org/project/azure-cli-core/ and https://github.com/Azure/azure-cli/

Comment: Expanded. I need to select which subscription to act on in a Python script.

Comment: Is your question: **How do I list my Azure subscriptions in Python**?

Comment: No. "How do I set the Azure Subscription for these X Python commands?" Sometimes a Python script will operate on multiple Azure Subscriptions ("Take a secret from Key Vault Secret 1 in Subscription A. Use the secret to provision resources in Subscription B."). For the first 3 commands `az account set --subscription $desiredSub` could be used for Subscription A, for the last 3 commands `az account set --subscription $desiredSub` would be aimed at Sub B.

Comment: If you are writing a Python script why are you concerned about the CLI? I do not understand your question. Are you trying to modify the CLI environment from Python?